# iOS app full screen issue

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I have problem with my app for iOS (Android build looks fine)
I build it with Cocoon webview

Heres my problem:
App launches ok but sometimes (lets say one out of ten launches) it just dont fill entire screen so at the bottom i have black bar.
Entire app is a bit shrinked but since i use scale out sides stay covered.
observe images:

[image]

[image]

First looks OK and secong is a bit smaller.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

heres my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" version="1.0" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
        <name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</name>
        <description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</description>
        <author href="xxxxxxxxx" email="xxxxxxxx">xxxxxxx</author>
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0"/>
        <access origin="*"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file"/>
        <access origin="*"/>
        <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library"/>
        <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root"/>
        <allow-intent href="file://*/*"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"/>
        <access origin="*"/>
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
        <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="file://*/*"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine"/>
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
        </feature>
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
        <preference name="webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior" value="never"/>
        <engine name="ios"/>
        <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-indexeddb" spec="*"/>
        <platform name="ios">
            <preference name="enabled" value="true"/>
            <name>xxxxxxxx</name>
            <splash src="www/splash/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png"/>
            <splash src="www/splash/ios/Defaulf-Portrait-2436h.png"/>
        </platform>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="*"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="*"/>
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-non-exempt-encryption" spec="*"/>
    </widget>
```

help please....  :(